# How can I connect my coffee machine with my phone via bluetooth?

Tags: arduino, hardware

I want to connect my coffee maker with my phone so that I can turn it on and off wirelessly. I understand that I have to use some kind of relay and a bluetooth module with arduino, but my coffee maker is old and doesn't have a board inside so none of the online tutorials help. For reference my coffee maker is very similar to this one: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Holstein-Housewares-5-Cup-Coffee-Maker-with-Removable-filter/170970272 (I couldn't find a schematic online).

Comment: this is a hardware-question. This is a programming community... just connect a relay parallel to the switch that turns it on. But I'd recommend that you get some knowledge about electronics first. someone who asks such questions should not handle lethal voltages.

Comment: You're right about both things, I initially thought I could ask hardware questions as well. But since you seem to know more, do you know of any resources (books, video series) which can give me the knowledge I need to pursue this safely?

Comment: Make has published some nice electonics beginners books but you're bascially ok with every entry level book. you basically need to understand why your device was built like that. otherwise you'll risk to compromise it's safety features. in the worst case you're getting a shock or burn your house down ;) but I definitely encourage you to take a look into devices. there is a lot to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different ways to solve it. If you just want a wireless switch, it is better if you get something on the web and connect your AC plug to your new switch.

If you want integrate your circuit in the machine for more features like make a coffee, you need also a power supply.

What you need is:
- Arduino
- a power supply 230V/5V (or 110V/5V), since Arduino works with 5V.
- a relais module to switch on and off your coffee machine - check this tutorial: https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/control-high-voltage-devices-arduino-relay-tutorial/
- HC05 module

Finally an android app for the HC05 module. Something like this one:
https://maker.pro/arduino/tutorial/bluetooth-basics-how-to-control-led-using-smartphone-arduino

Instead of powering on the led, you have to powering the coffee machine.